# Consolidate nested arrays into one array

Tags: php, arrays, collections

I have an object-arraylist with the attributes coordinates.

How would I go about flattening that array. By flattening, I mean keeping the coordinate arrays, but information in the additional arrays should be pushed inside the first array at the end.

```
"checksum": "b29e57b048be1ff004de37679c6f6ea4",
"type": "LineString",
"color": "#0000ff",
"text": "",
"count": 2,
"length": 1,
"coordinates": [
  [
    [
      1245613.4845831,
      8456782.8389739
    ],
    [
      1245612.5888367,
      8456786.5712507
    ],
    [
      1245611.3945081,
      8456792.6921846
    ],
    [
      1245611.9916724,
      8456795.678006
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      1245560.9341261,
      8456793.1400578
    ],
    [
      1245561.6805815,
      8456795.528715
    ],
    [
      1245562.2777458,
      8456797.9173721
    ],
    [
      1245564.3678208,
      8456797.9173721
    ],
    [
      1245565.7114404,
      8456802.8439774
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      1245560.9341261,
      8456793.1400578
    ],
    [
      1245561.6805815,
      8456795.528715
    ],
    [
      1245562.2777458,
      8456797.9173721
    ],
    [
      1245564.3678208,
      8456797.9173721
    ],
    [
      1245565.7114404,
      8456802.8439774
    ]
  ]
]
```

How I would like the coordinates array sorted:

```
"coordinates": [
    [
      [
        1245613.4845831,
        8456782.8389739
      ],
      [
        1245612.5888367,
        8456786.5712507
      ],
      [
        1245611.3945081,
        8456792.6921846
      ],
      [
        1245611.9916724,
        8456795.678006
      ],
      [
        1245560.9341261,
        8456793.1400578
      ],
      [
        1245561.6805815,
        8456795.528715
      ],
      [
        1245562.2777458,
        8456797.9173721
      ],
      [
        1245564.3678208,
        8456797.9173721
      ],
      [
        1245565.7114404,
        8456802.8439774
      ],
      [
        1245560.9341261,
        8456793.1400578
      ],
      [
        1245561.6805815,
        8456795.528715
      ],
      [
        1245562.2777458,
        8456797.9173721
      ],
      [
        1245564.3678208,
        8456797.9173721
      ],
      [
        1245565.7114404,
        8456802.8439774
      ]

    ]
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to extract `coordinate`?
If it is the case, you can do `$newArr = array('coordinate'=>$oldArray['coordinates']);`

Comment: That just gives me an extra array

"coordinates": {
      "coordinate": [
        [
          [
            1245613.4845831,
            8456782.8389739
          ],
]

I need everything inside the main coordinates array. If you look closely there are in fact 3 arrays inside on main array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply iterate on coordinates to build the flattened array :

```
$coordinatesOnly = $original['coordinates'];
$flattenedCoordinates = [];
foreach ($coordinatesOnly as $coordinatesSet) {
  $flattenedCoordinates = array_merge($flattenedCoordinates, $coordinatesSet);
}
var_dump($flattenedCoordinates);
```

Given your original array :

```
$original = [
  'checksum' => 'b29e57b048be1ff004de37679c6f6ea4',
  'type' => 'LineString',
  'color' => '#0000ff',
  'text' => '',
  'count' => 2,
  'length' => 1,
  'coordinates' => [
    [
      [
        1245613.4845831,
        8456782.8389739
      ],
      [
        1245612.5888367,
        8456786.5712507
      ],
      [
        1245611.3945081,
        8456792.6921846
      ],
      [
        1245611.9916724,
        8456795.678006
      ]
    ],
    [
      [
        1245560.9341261,
        8456793.1400578
      ],
      [
        1245561.6805815,
        8456795.528715
      ],
      [
        1245562.2777458,
        8456797.9173721
      ],
      [
        1245564.3678208,
        8456797.9173721
      ],
      [
        1245565.7114404,
        8456802.8439774
      ] ],
    [
      [
        1245560.9341261,
        8456793.1400578
      ],
      [
        1245561.6805815,
        8456795.528715
      ],
      [
        1245562.2777458,
        8456797.9173721
      ],
      [
        1245564.3678208,
        8456797.9173721
      ],
      [
        1245565.7114404,
        8456802.8439774
      ]
    ]
  ]
];
```

You get what you expect :

```
array(14) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    float(1245613.4845831)
    [1]=>
    float(8456782.8389739)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    float(1245612.5888367)
    [1]=>
    float(8456786.5712507)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    float(1245611.3945081)
    [1]=>
    float(8456792.6921846)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    float(1245611.9916724)
    [1]=>
    float(8456795.678006)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    float(1245560.9341261)
    [1]=>
    float(8456793.1400578)
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    float(1245561.6805815)
    [1]=>
    float(8456795.528715)
  }
  [6]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    float(1245562.2777458)
    [1]=>
    float(8456797.9173721)
  }
  [7]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    float(1245564.3678208)
    [1]=>
    float(8456797.9173721)
  }
  [8]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    float(1245565.7114404)
    [1]=>
    float(8456802.8439774)
  }
  [9]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    float(1245560.9341261)
    [1]=>
    float(8456793.1400578)
  }
  [10]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    float(1245561.6805815)
    [1]=>
    float(8456795.528715)
  }
  [11]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    float(1245562.2777458)
    [1]=>
    float(8456797.9173721)
  }
  [12]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    float(1245564.3678208)
    [1]=>
    float(8456797.9173721)
  }
  [13]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    float(1245565.7114404)
    [1]=>
    float(8456802.8439774)
  }
}
```

Comment: You are so correct! Thank you so much for helping me se the obvious in disguise :) Think this is the best answer due to details

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through the nested values and merge all of them in a new array:
here, `$old` is the initial `coordinates` nested array.

```
$new = array();
foreach($old as $oldNest){
    $new = array_merge($new, $oldNest);
}
```